# If I use a preset for a synthesizer VST in a song and make a commercial use of the song, do I need some license for this preset?

Tags: united-states, licensing, music

Assume one uses a preset for some synthesizer [VST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology) in a song and make a commercial use of the song: does one need some license for this preset? I live in the United States.

Comment: Since preset packs are [often] sold/licensed as software, I'd say yes. The same goes for the samples often involved in modern "romplers". If you read the agreements for the latter they are fairly generous but also rather specific, e.g. you can include the result in a song, but not resell the samples as such or as part of a collection of samples.

Comment: Thanks, good points.